# C - Unable read data from Input Stream

Tags: c, linux, gcc, terminal, scanf

This is the code that I wrote in C.

```
void BFS()
{
    int index[4][2];
    int p=10,i,j,x,y;
    int chld=-1;
    int cnt=1;
    int size=sizeof(NODE);
    char ch='n';
    qstart=NULL;
    lstart=NULL;
    NODE *ptr,*tmp;
    NODE* broot=(NODE*)malloc(size);
    NODE* bgoal=(NODE*)malloc(size);
    memcpy(broot,root,size);
    memcpy(bgoal,goal,size);
    push_queue(broot);


    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    //This scanf does not work well, don't read from input stream or console
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    printf("Want to see the nodes\t[y/n]\n");
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    printf("\n\nTOTAL NODE COUNT ");
    //---------------------------------------------------------------



    while(p>0)
    {
        if((ptr=pop_queue())!=NULL)
        {
            positions(ptr,index,&x,&y);
            if(ch=='y' || ch=='Y')
            {
                printf("\t\t\tParent\n");
                print_node(ptr);
            }
            i=0;    j=0;    chld=-1;
            for(i=0;i<4;i++)
                if(index[i][0]!=-1)
                if((tmp=node_exchange(ptr,broot,index[i][0],index[i][1],x,y))!=NULL)
                {
                    printf("%d",cnt);
                    j=cnt;
                    cnt++;
                    tmp->parent=ptr;
                    ptr->child[++chld]=tmp;
                    if(!memcmp(tmp,bgoal,9*sizeof(int)))
                    {
                        trace_path(tmp);
                        printf("Total Nodes Skipped : %d",TOTAL_SKIP);
                        free_list();
                        return ;
                    }
                    push_queue(tmp);
                    push_list(tmp);
                    while(j>0)
                    {
                        j=j/10;
                        printf("\b");
                    }
                }
            if(ch=='y' || ch=='Y')
                print_child(ptr,chld);
            for(i=chld+1;i<4;i++)
                ptr->child[i]=NULL;
        }
        else{
            printf("WARNING: popped null\n");
            break;
        }
//      p--;
    }
    qstart=NULL;
}
```

This is one function of my program. The scanf call (marked inside the code by comments) does not read from console. It keeps executing all codes after that and does not wait for the input which it should do. I'm using gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) (GCC) and gnome terminal.

The sample output is :
Please enter the intial state:
            The Initial Node

```
          0  1  2
          3  4  5
          6  7  8
```

Please enter the goal node:
            The Goal Node

```
          8  7  6
          5  4  3
          2  1  0
```

**Want to see the nodes [y/n]**

TOTAL NODE COUNT 885^C

Trust me, I've no idea why such a thing is happening.It should wait after the statement **Want to see the nodes [y/n]**, but it doesn't and keeps executing further.

Comment: Change `scanf("%c",&ch);` to `scanf(" %c",&ch);`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`fgetc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetc/), like this:

```
ch = fgetc(stdin);
```

This will read one character from `stdin`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `getch()` or `getche()`.
I think that `getche()` would be better because it echoes the character pressed. 
Generally, when you give a "yes or no" prompt in a program, and  the default is "no", the 'n' is capitalized: `[y/N]`.